# Perl search and replace in a Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, perl

I have been trying to replace some text in a .txt file using a shell script and perl.

```
oldKey=123
trimmedNewKey=456

#Export shell variables, so that they can be used by perl
export oldKey
export trimmedNewKey

#Search and Replace
perl -pi -e 's/$ENV{oldKey}/$ENV{trimmedNewKey}/g' AppConstants.txt
```

This fails, but on the other hand, if I use string directly for the search param, it works:

```
perl -pi -e 's/123/$ENV{trimmedNewKey}/g' AppConstants.txt.
```

I am not a shell guy and can't figure out why my "search" param can't be evaluated via a variable. Help !

Comment: The two snippets you claim produce different outcome are actually equivalent except for the differences in file names (`AppConstants.txt` vs `AppConstants.txt.`) Assuming that's not what you mean, please provide an actual demonstration of the problem as required.

Comment: Is the value of `oldKey` supposed to be matched literally, or is it a regex pattern? If the former, you should be using `s/\Q$ENV{oldKey}/.../g`.

Comment: Your code works fine here, please give example of input file and expected output

Comment: @ikegami This did the  trick. Could you please add it as an answer with some explanation for the \Q. I always thought we have to provide a string in the search pattern whether its a regex or a literal.

Comment: @nr5, Sure. Fix the question so it exhibits the problem, and I'll post an answer.

Comment: You always have to provide a regex pattern, whether it's a a compiled regex object (from `qr//`) or a string. (Anything else will get stringified.)

Comment: @ikegami good to know. I'll be happy to accept it as the answer, please add it.

Comment: Will do. Let me know when the question is fixed.

Comment: @ikegami I think it's clear no? I was trying to replace the string literal via a variable which was getting stringified when used like the replacement string format but worked when used like a regex. What's left to add here ?

Comment: It's clear that what you said is completely untrue. Until you demonstrate a problem as required,  I can't help you fix it!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your code into

```
oldKey=123
trimmedNewKey=456
perl -pi -e "s/$oldKey/$trimmedNewKey/g" AppConstants.txt
```

This should work, because in a string enclosed in single quotes, there is no variable and wildcard expansion, as it is the case in a string enclosed in double quotes.

It is possible perhaps to pass some variables to perl so that the expansion happens inside the perl program, but why to make it complex when you can solve it in an easier way?

Comment: It would probably be faster if you use **sed** instead of **perl**, as follows: `sed -i "s/$oldKey/$trimmedNewKey/g" AppConstants.txt`

Comment: That's a horrible idea. You've just added a number of bugs without fixing anyhing